# How to find what CSP version a particular browser version is supporting?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, xss, content-security-policy

As I understand there's CSPv2 and CSPv3. Also, browsers implement support for these at different time, if I understand correctly. I have two chrome browsers running on two computers, with the same version numbers, but one gives `object-src` violation error and does not load the PDF and the other does not give the error and successfully loads the PDF - located by the same URL.

1. Is there a way I can look at someplace in the browser and know the CSP version it supports? Ex: Chrome vxxxx.xxxx supports CSPvX.
2. Also where can I know the details of different CSP released versions? *W3C* talks about a CSP Level 3 but *content-security-policy.com* only talks about a CSP Level 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CSPv1 and CSPv2, you can check the following links for browser support information.

CSPv1: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy

CSPv2: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2

For CSPv3, it is too early to check browser support data (CSPv2 is release in December 15th 2016 and CSPv3 is in *Working Draft* status). Actually, some CSPv3 features are still under development in Chrome (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4626666856906752) and no public information is released yet for other browsers.